# How to FTS-match from 2 different columns

Tags: sqlite, fts5

I am trying to search 2 separate columns called `keyword` and `keyword2` for a match. Can this be done with SQLite FTS?

I've tried this statement but it did not work:

```
String sql = "Select * from tblvHAL2001 WHERE tblvHAL2001 MATCH 'keyword:" + question + "' OR MATCH 'keyword2:" + question +"'";
```

Comment: FTS5 is the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only a single FTS query per table. FTS does have [boolean operators](http://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#fts5_boolean_operators):

```
... WHERE tblvHAL2001 MATCH 'keyword: "blah" OR keyword2: "blah"'
```

And in FTS5, a single [column filter](http://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#fts5_column_filters) can specify multiple columns:

```
... WHERE tblvHAL2001 MATCH '{keyword keyword2}: "blah"'
```

Comment: You sir are a legend!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE tblvHAL2001 MATCH '{keyword keyword2}: "blah"'
```